# Problema de formato con Access

Tags: ms-access

Tengo un Access en el que hay unos Excel vinculados (no importados). Estos Excel tienen varias columnas de fechas, y en todas ellas salvo en una, lo detecta correctamente como fecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si abro el Excel en particular, me aparece correctamente como una fecha en Excel, pero no en Access, y no me deja cambiar el `Data Type` manualmente. En modo visualización se puede ver como el formato de las columnas correctas se ve diferente que el de la columna incorrecta, y en ambas columnas hay los mismos valores (mayoritariamente fechas y algunas almohadillas, pero las almohadillas no son problema para las otras columnas):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo arreglarlo?
Gracias.

Comment: *Si abro el Excel en particular, me aparece correctamente como una fecha en Excel* Ten en cuenta que en Excel una cosa es lo que vemos en la celda (formato) y otra cosa el valor que realmente hay en la celda (value, el valor que aparece en la barra de fórmulas al seleccionar una celda y aplicar formato General), que es lo que Access te está cogiendo. En cualquier caso, para tratarlo podrías añadir un campo calculado en la propia tabla y formularlo bien para convertirlo, o mediante consulta también con un campo calculado. Todo depende de lo que vayas a hacer luego con ese campo.

Comment: Lo que dice Esei es correcto. El problema va a estar en el formato de las celdas de cada columna de campo. Ej. Po Document Date. Ahora bien, yo no me complicaba creando nuevos campos calculados.

Comment: Lo que veo más fácil es que en Excel: -En una nueva columna, verifica selecionado toda la columna el formato de todas las celdas de la columna, A:A Por ejemplo. En Formato de la Celda (botón derecho) selecciona un formato de fecha. 
-Copia toda la columna del campo con error y pega en la nueva columna solo los valores. (es una opción de pegado, que se representa como 123)
Con eso te aseguras que los datos y el formato son los correctos.
Repite/repara para cada campo que esté mal vinculado a Access, todo siempre en Excel.